# How to get all of the array values out of a dictionary of lists as a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays of the following format:

```
letters = {1: ['h'], 2: ['e'], 3: ['l', 'l'], 4: ['o']}
```

I'd like to know how I can get all of the values out of the arrays within the `letters` dict, bearing in mind that there may be single or multiple values within each one and the array values may be duplicates. So for the above example, I'd want the following output:

```
letter_values = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

although the output needn't necessarily be in order.

I know how to get the values out of a dictionary using `dict.values()`, but not when there is an additional layer of abstraction like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing this question (as is often the case), I figured out the answer.

You just need to use the `dict.values()` functionality to obtain a list of lists, and then concatenate those lists (for which there is a convenient shorthand), like so:

```
letter_values = [item for sublist in letters.values() for item in sublist]
```

Where `item` and `sublist` are just throwaway variables.

Easy!

([A reminder](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

Comment: no need for `list(letters.values())`, just `letters.values()` will do